# How can I do sub selects on already selected element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Markup:

```
<div class="foo">
    <img src="loading.gif" class="loading" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

Js:

```
$("div[class='foo']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $(/* somehow select the loading img of exactly this div with class foo (not others) */).show();
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$("div[class='foo']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $('img.loading', this).show();
});
```

Comment: Wow! You can pass context to the $-selector! Nice.

Comment: @randomguy: Selector context maps to the *find()* method, so `$('img.loading', this)` is the same as `$(this).find('img.loading')`.  Selector context is much "nicer", I think.

Answer (score 27):

If you want any descendant of the given element you can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find(".foo");
```

If you know you only want to search for the first-level children elements, you can use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$(this).children(".foo");
```

Comment: I like the hint to children(".foo")

Comment: Indeed correct -- but depending the way you understand _sub selects_ in the question title, elements of the initial set _might_ be candidate for selection. But as far as I know, `find` will not consider descendants. I don't know if there is a way to find in "self or descendants" though...

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$(this).find("img").show();
```

or

```
$(this).find("img.loading").show();
```